# Find and replace data which always changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file which contains around 130k rows of this information in cell A1:

I tried using find and replace, but for that to work the information must always be 1:1 and the below information is always different.

**(numbers are fictitious)*

```
"Account": "751921385718",
"Password": "328520520511",
"Number": "14032050184310"
```

I would like to change the above info to:

```
"Account": "",
"Password": "",
"Number": ""
```

How can I achieve this using VBA?

Comment: Is all that 'information' in cell "A1"?  Or in cells of A:A column? Are there three such rows inside of any cell in the range?

Comment: Cell character limit is ~32k I thought, so not clear how you got 130k rows of data in a cell?  If each line is really in a separate cell then `newValue =Split(cellValue,":")(0) & ":"""","`

Comment: Do you mean, you do not know what is to be replaced? Please, translate what "data which always changes" means... Do you want making all cells looking as in your "changed info"?

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru I mean that I do not know what is to be replaced. So we have certain titles like account in this exact format "Account": "112345678910" and I would like to replace the numbers what ever the value of the numbers are they need to be replaced, sometimes there are numbers sometimes there are letters.

Comment: Then the solution offered by @Tim Williams, who better understood your question, should work.  Now, are there all the mentioned lines in the same "A1" cell? Are they in all A:A column? Are they groups of three lines in A:A cells?

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru they are all in A:A column. Each line is a different title.

Comment: Meaning each example line on a column cell... So in what you show there are three A:A consecutive cells. Is it correct? If yes, you can easily use @Tim Williams's solution.

Comment: Yes thats correct, I tried @TimWilliams solution, but I could not edit it to make it work. I'm not advanced in VBA sadly.

Comment: I am only not able to understand why he two first lines end in a comma, and a third one not. That's why I supposed that three of them are in a single cell. You should iterate between each cell, but faster will be to place the column in an array, process it and then drop down the result. Do you like to let the "Number" without the ending comma?

Comment: I will delete my answer, in fact, I will adapt it to use the Tim William's suggestion. So, all credit should go to him.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru I also don't know why the number does not end with a comma, we open a JSON file in Excel to edit it.

Comment: @FaneDuru Ty very much do I get notified when you update the answer with Tim William's suggestion?

Comment: OK. I will make the code returning as in your JSON file... I mean, to skip the comma for the string starting with "Number"...

Comment: I will do it in a minute... And yes, you will be notified. But if you like it, please mark Tim's answer as accepted answer. A vote up for me will be OK. :)

Comment: Posted the answer. Please, observe that it will return in B:B!. If you like the processing result, you can easily adapt the code to return in A:A, replacing the existing range values. The code, using arrays, should be very fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell character limit is ~32k I thought, so not clear how you got 130k rows of data in a cell?

If each line is really in a separate cell then

```
newValue = Split(cellValue,":")(0) & ": """","
```

If you do have multiple lines per cell then split each cell on `vbLf` and apply the above to each element in that array, then join it back using `vbLf`

Answer (score 2):

Please, use the next way to solve your problem. It uses Tim William's suggestion, so **all the credit should go to him**:

```
Sub ReplaceStringsWithNullString()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet, or simple activate the one to be processed
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).value
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = ReplaceString(arr(i, 1))
   Next i
   sh.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).value = arr
End Sub

Function ReplaceString(strVal) As String
    If left(strVal, 8) = """Number""" Then
        ReplaceString = Split(strVal, ":")(0) & ": """""
    Else
        ReplaceString = Split(strVal, ":")(0) & ": """","
    End If
End Function
```

The sub returns in column B:B. If you like its result, it is easy to adapt the code to return back in A:A.

Comment: This works, but here I have to put in the numbers manually, which still takes a lot of time. I'm looking for a more automatic way to replace what ever comes after "Account":